# What is the meaning of the note below in [expr.reinterpret.cast]/6?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, function-pointers, reinterpret-cast

[[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#6):

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer
>   of a different type. [ **Note: The effect of calling a function through
>   a pointer to a function type ([dcl.fct]) that is not the same as the
>   type used in the definition of the function is undefined. — end note** ]
>   Except that converting a prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type
>   “pointer to T2” (where T1 and T2 are function types) and back to its
>   original type yields the original pointer value, the result of such a
>   pointer conversion is unspecified. [ Note: See also [conv.ptr] for
>   more details of pointer conversions. — end note ]

It seems to me this note is saying that the following snippet (see [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1ffe28c66ecb388)) has undefined behavior. Is this correct? Or is there something else besides this?

```
#include<iostream>
void f() { std::cout << "function returning void\n"; }
int g() { std::cout << "function returning int\n"; return 1; }

int main(){
    void (*pf)() = f;
    reinterpret_cast<int(*)()>(pf)();
}
```

Comment: This is correct. Undefined behavior.

Comment: And probably very bad, because it expects something on the stack that is not there. Complete stack breakage.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the note is that the function pointer can be converted, but that the result may not be used.  However, the result can be converted *back* to the original type before use.  The idea is to store one of several function pointer types in a single variable (without requiring a `union`) along with a tag that indicates (somehow) the actual function type.

Note that you cannot portably convert a function pointer to an *object* pointer (*e.g.*, `void*`) at all.  However, POSIX [assumes you can do this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html), so it very often works.

Comment: "_Note that you cannot portably_" Exactly. In *practice* you can (almost always) hopefully.